# Description of a point cloud being "undersampled" wrt persistent homology, confidence level?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, st.statistics, computational-geometry, computational-topology, persistent-homology

I am completely new to topological data analysis, so I apologise if this is a well-known area of persistent homology, as well as for any imprecise language.

Suppose we know completely the topological features of a manifold $M$. Is there a sense in which a point cloud sampled from $M$ might be "undersampled"? In other words, can we identify a threshold for the number of points sampled at which the persistent homology computed (say, if a barcode of the $k$<sup>th</sup> homology lasts for a given length of time $t$) has a less than 95% confidence level?

If so, then can we say something about how many points a point cloud sampled from a manifold with partial information on topological features (e.g., dimension) should have to avoid "undersampling"?

Comment: I have found [these](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.7117) [three](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.6437) [papers](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume16/chazal15a/chazal15a.pdf), but I am not sure if/how they're related to my question.

Comment: Bobrowski's recent paper "On the universality of random persistence diagrams" describes asymptotic behaviour when computing persistent homology of RIPS complexes of point clouds sampled from parametric distributions.  So if you are generating your data this way, it gives you a concrete test for whether or not you have under-sampled.